# OpenLayers 3: Omit SelectInteraction after DrawInteraction

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have a map with a `ol.interaction.Select` and I add to it a `ol.interaction.Draw` when I want to place some new Object (a Point).

Now as soon as I click to create the `Point`, the `selectInteraction` fires the `select` event. As the `drawend` event fires before the `select` event, I'm not able to determine, if it was a genuine `select` or if it happened because I'm drawing.

I also tried, to activate/deactivate the `selectInteraction` with a `setTimeout` in the `drawend` event, with no luck. As soon as I activate the `selectInteraction`, the `select` event fires.

Comment: Maybe you show a bit of your logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Propably, this is happening because the single-click event is taking place 251ms after you clicked. It is a known issue -->[check it here](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/3610). It is build that way so double click can be recognised. Having both interactions active is caussing problems for sure. Someone has to deside. Is it select? or is it draw? or both? so ol3 desides that if you set both of them active that means you want both of them active.
Disable the select interaction on `drawstart` and then on `drawend` try to enable your select interaction 251ms after the drawend event occurs. like sο:

```
setTimeout(function(){
selectInteraction.setActive(true)
},300)
;
```

Though, this is bad programming. But I cannt really find an elegand way to overcome it.

Comment: I can't believe it but it works like a charm. My stomach twists and turns but I will have to implement it this way...Thank you very much!

Comment: no probs amigo. glad to help. Dont worry about your stomach, as long as it works it will get better and better. :))))))